# What happens to permissions when installing release version of apk using adb

Tags: android, apk, adb

Recently , I got a release version apk of some 3rd party application. I installed it using adb

```
adb install <path to apk>
```

But when I run it , I get the error message

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/<package name>/logging.properties (Permission denied)
```

So what happens to the permissions?

Why was I not asked about the permissions?

Were they granted to the application implicitly?

I am guessing the application should have asked me about it but it did not. How can I run this application? I am using an emulator to test, by the way.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install using `adb install` permission are granted implicitly. This is a developer tool after all. The 'permission denied' message looks like a bug: either the app is missing the 'READ/WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission or it can't find the file and is giving you a wrong message.